# How can I delete a dulicate values of a data frame without lose information and gouping it from another variable?

Tags: r, database

This is the "data.frame" with I am working to

[image]

I am trying to delete duplicate values from the `conflict_id` variable but without losing any information for the variable "side_b". My only idea was to delete it this way.

```r
data2 <- data[!duplicated(data$conflict_id),]
```

The result is this one :

[image]

Like you see the result is that R takes all the values that are not the same in `coflict_id` without grouping the values of `side_b`

My question is, how can I delete the duplicate values in `conflict_id` and group the values of `side_b` without losing any information?

Comment: @Arash Hatami I attach you the expected output, tell me if you know how to fix it.

Comment: Removing duplicates in one column while preserving all possible data in the others can lead in two directions, and there is no indication which way you want to go: (1) concatenate the strings, for instance 267 may become `"EPRP, TPLF; EDU, EPRP; EDU, TPLF; ..."`; or (2) list-columns, outside the scope of a simple comment (but search for `"r" "list-columns"` and you'll find some examples). Also, I'm tired of transcribing data to address questions when you have the data readily available. Please use `dput(head(x,20))` (or some representative size with some dupes) and your expected output.

Answer (score -1):

@akrum
Here is the ouput with your code "distinct(conflict_id, .keepall = TRUE)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhCLw.png)

I need something like this

conflict_id      side_b
263              FNLA, MPLA, UNITA

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a response to a (since-deleted) answer. Please delete this. If it is appropriate for the question itself, then put it *there*. Thanks.